# HiveQL - Rlike to a regexp in a field?

Tags: regex, join, hiveql, rlike

Can you use rlike to join a table using regular expressions contained in a field?

i.e.
Select a.*, b.*
from Table a 
inner join Table2 b
on a.Field rlike b.Field2

i.e. Table 2 data:
Field1 Field2
David  ^D(a|o)vid
Test a ^Test

Answer (score 0):

Just worked out that I can do this.

select a.*, b.*
from  Table1 a, Table2 b
where b.Field1 rlike a.Field2